# The type or namespace name 'Score' could not be found

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I don't know why, but I see to be getting thrown this error.. I followed a tutorial and haven't missed anything so far but now I have come to this.

> The type or namespace name 'Score' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

**PlayerMotor.cs**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class PlayerMotor : MonoBehaviour
{
    private CharacterController controller;
    private Vector3 moveVector;

    private float speed = 10.0f;
    private float verticalVelocity = 0.0f;
    private float gravity = 12.0f;

    private float animationDuration = 3.0f;

    private bool isDead = false;

    void Start () {
        controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    }

    void Update () {

        if (isDead)
            return;

        if(Time.time < animationDuration)
        {
            controller.Move(Vector3.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime);
            return;
        }

        moveVector = Vector3.zero;

        if(controller.isGrounded)
        {
            verticalVelocity = -0.5f;
        }
        else
        {
            verticalVelocity -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;
        }

        // X - Left and Right
        moveVector.x = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * speed;

        // Y - Up and Dow
        moveVector.y = verticalVelocity;

        // Z - Forward and Backward
        moveVector.z = speed;


        controller.Move (moveVector * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    public void SetSpeed(float modifier)
    {
        speed = 10.0f + modifier;
    }

    private void OnControllerColliderHit (ControllerColliderHit hit)
        {
        if (hit.point.z > transform.position.z + controller.radius)
            Death();
        }

    private void Death()
    {
        isDead = true;
        GetComponent<Score>().OnDeath();
    }
}
```

**Score.cs**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Score : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float score = 0.0f;

    private int difficultyLevel = 1;
    private int maxDifficultyLevel = 10;
    private int scoreToNextLevel = 10;

    private bool isDead = false;

    public Text scoreText;

    void Update () {

        if (isDead)
            return;

        if (score >= scoreToNextLevel)
            LevelUp();

        score += Time.deltaTime * difficultyLevel;
        scoreText.text = ((int)score).ToString ();
    }

    void LevelUp()
    {
        if (difficultyLevel == maxDifficultyLevel)
            return;

        scoreToNextLevel *= 2;
        difficultyLevel++;

        GetComponent<PlayerMotor>().SetSpeed (difficultyLevel);

        Debug.Log (difficultyLevel);
    }

    public void OnDeath()
    {
        isDead = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Save the code, then go to Unity editor, double click on the error and tell us which line of code contains the error

Comment: I guess its here `GetComponent<Score>().OnDeath();`? Are you sure that you attached the "Score" script to same gameobject?

Comment: GetComponent<Score>().OnDeath(); <- This is the error and Yes, "Score" is attached to the player

Comment: @ŁukaszMotyczka You don't get compile time error if that's the case. If that's the problem, run-time null error would occur not compile time error.

Comment: Well I got the half of the problem :) Will I get 0.5 points?

Comment: @ŁukaszMotyczka Sure. A comment upvote.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing both the scripts you have mentioned here are not attached to the same game object.
A quick fix to this would be to create a variable for the score script in your PlayerMotor script and then drag the score script to the variable in the editor to set it. 
or you could just 
do

```
GameObject.Find("Player").GetComponent<Score>().OnDeath();
```

or maybe you destroy the gameobject of the player on death, in that case nothing will work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not evening joking, I closed everything, reopened it and it works.

I'm done

Comment: That's Unity for you. Sometimes, closing and re-opening it solves your problem.